# Trying to make an age calculator, but I have some problems when trying to make error "line"

Tags: python

I think the title says it all but I'll give you the code.

```
stop=0
while stop != 'q':
print("Age calculator")
name = input("Name: ")
print("Type in your age")
age = input("Age: ")

months = age * 12
days = age * 365
weeks = age * 52
hours = days * 24
minutes = age * 525948
seconds = age * 31556926

if type(age) == int:
   print (name, "lives for", months, "months", weeks, "weeks", days, "days", hours, "hours", minutes, "minutes and", seconds, "seconds")

else:
   print("Please type in a number")


print()
print("Try again? Press ENTER")
print("Quit? Press 'q' and then ENTER")
print()
stop = input()
```

So the thing is that I want it to give you the months, weeks, days etc.
Now I know how to do this but now I'm trying to make a line that would say: Please type in a number. If the user would type in characters instead of numbers. When I run this code above every time I type in a number it gives me the line "Please type in a number" and when I type in a character it does the same.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: What values did `months`, `days`, etc. get assigned?

Comment: What do you mean by that? I'm sorry, I just started into Python.

Comment: `input()` returns a string, regardless of whether the input was a number or a set of characters. That's why your `if type(age) == int` fails.

Comment: Dylan, Welcome to SO. You should read up on "typecasting" and "datatypes." While Python is not as strongly typed when declaring variables as some other languages, your data type from `input` is a string (as John Mark said). You will need cast the string type to an int (or at least attempt to).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Input() statement accepts all type of input as string so even if you enter an integer it will be a string like "1" so you need to typecast the given input() as int() either type cast it seperately or if you typecast directly at input() statement then it ll create exception type error so you can use try catch alto repeat the program. So if you use try catch then code will be.

```
status=""
try: 
    while True:
          print("Age calculator")
          name = input("Name: ")
          print("Type in your age")
          age = input("Age: ")
          age=int(age)
          months = age * 12
          days = age * 365
          weeks = age * 52
          hours = days * 24
          minutes = age * 525948
          seconds = age * 31556926
          print (name, "lives for", months, "months", weeks, "weeks", days, "days", hours, "hours", minutes, "minutes and", seconds, "seconds")
         print("Try again? Press ENTER")
         status = input("Quit? Press 'q' and then ENTER")
         if status = "q":
              break # terminates program if "q" is entered.
except TypeError:
          print("Please type in a number for age")
          continue #runs program till "q"is passed as age.
except:
    raise # this raises error if something goes wrong
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

When you read in input it's always read in as a string. You need to cast your input to int like

```
int(input("Age: "))
```

Note that this will break if the user enters a letter instead of a number, to get around that without changing your code too much you could keep your input statements as they are change your if statement to the following.

```
try: 
    age = int(age)
    print statement

except ValueError:
    print("Please type in a number")
```

Another important thing to keep in mind is that in your code you have operators acting on age before it is assigned to an int, that means

```
age * 12
```

actually gives you a str ('555555555555' if the age passed in was 5) instead of a number. To fix this you should move the statements into the try so that they are called after the number is converted to an integer

Comment: Thanks for the help!